# Session value gets deleted after redircing with payment gateway?

Tags: php, session, payment-gateway

My Application is using MonesterPay payment method.
I am storing some user information in session variable as it will use after transaction is complete successfully.
But once my transaction is complete the session values gets deleted which I have stored.
Any solutions or reason there?

Comment: Did you set any expiration time?

Comment: No, there is not any expiration time but for your information it works with chrome browser but it is not working with Mozilla browser of any system!!

Comment: Can I have a look at what code you have written till yet for a better idea...

Comment: Hi,
You can check the code through below url:
http://115.252.73.130/vinod/userpayment.txt

At line no : 426 you can check there i am storing the session
and after payment line no : 547 when response comes then session not stored there. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would suggest is, you first create an order id for each transaction and store it in your database, and send the ID in the request form to monsterpay as a hidden baggage field.
Example -

```
<INPUT TYPE="HIDDEN" NAME="Option1name" VALUE="myUniqueTransactionID">
<INPUT TYPE="HIDDEN" NAME="Option1value" VALUE="12131">
```

These values will be passed back to your script upon the completion of the payment. You can cross check if the payment was successful by reading the response and mark the order ID as paid.